# Integrating viewpager with a listview

Tags: android

I have a listview, clicking on one of the item in listview takes me to some fragment (different item may take to different fragment). Once a new fragment is opened I want to swipe to open the the next item in list instead of going back and clicking on the next item. I am thinking of using ViewPagers but not sure how to open the next item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Activity` which has a `ViewPager` and `Fragments` with desired info as its children. On a list item click, take the position info and pass it to the `Activity` via `Bundle`. And inside the `Activity` after setting the `ViewPager`, you can show the desired `Fragment` with `ViewPager`'s `setCurrentItem(int item)` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have few questions. How does this work when i swipe left and right? Initial fragment will be displayed with the position but what about the others that I have to show when the user swipes? Thanks.